# how can show all titles of bar chart in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, charts, bar-chart

I'm Working With asp.net Chart (bar-chart)
In my result only show 3 bar title
How can show all titles of bar ?

please see attached picture
thanks

http://oi57.tinypic.com/1z72cuw.jpg

Comment: Add some code on how you are binding the data to the chart

Comment: Update your question, don't just send me a PM ;)